# Grub help: change from PXEboot to local boot

Tags: boot, grub2

I have a client node which currently boots over the network via PXEboot.  That works fine.

I want to change this. I want this node to boot from the local disk. So, I copied the remote OS root filesystem to the local disk on this node, and I want the node to boot directly from that local disk. However, I don't know how to configure GRUB (grub2) to allow this.

If I run `grub-mkconfig` it complains

```
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path from '192.168.1.1:/nfsroot'.
```

In this case, `192.168.1.1:/nfsroot` is the location of the remote mounted root filesystem that PXEboot uses.  I can't get any further than this.  With grub2, I'm not supposed to modify `grub.cfg`.

What should I do?

Comment: Can you chroot in this System? Can you show `cat /etc/fstab` ? and `sudo blkid ` inside chroot?

Comment: I solved it another way.  I had a spare partition so I simply installed Ubuntu 16 on the spare partition.  The installation process configured grub the right way (mostly).